# Created table in DAX, but can't extract the correct value

Tags: dax

I'm attempting to create a measure to give me the rank of a Salesman by Sales.  I'll use the measure in a table where one of the columns is Salesman, so there should be the appropriate row context applied.  But using
RETURN Calculate( MAXX (RankTable, [Rank] ) )
just gives me a value of 1 for every broker.  I can't figure out what to used to just pull out the value for Rank calculated in RankTable.  How do I do that?

```
SumSales = sumx( SalesData, [Sale])
----------
SalesRank = 
VAR SummaryTable = 
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        SUMMARIZE( SalesData, [Salesman] ),
        "Sales", [SumSales]
    )   
VAR RankTable = 
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        SummaryTable,
        "Rank", RANKX( SummaryTable, [Sales])
    )
RETURN 
    Calculate( MAXX (RankTable, [Rank] ) )
```

I know that RankTable is correct, since DAX Studio give me this result:

Salesman  Sales   Rank

A   907 1

B   600 3

C   900 2

D   500 4

Here's code for measure mentioned in comments:

```
Priced. = 
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER( 'Cases',
        [Date Initiated] >= [MinDate]
        && [Date Initiated] <= [MaxDate]
        && not ISBLANK( [Date To Pricing] )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be overcomplicating things, this should work:

```
SalesRank = RANKX(ALL('Salesdata'[Salesman]), [SumSales])
```

Reason you're getting 1 for every line is because in a visual the measure is calculated in the context containing a single salesman. So you need to remove this filter using the ALL() function.

Comment: Yep, that works fine!
I've been working with DAX for about a year now, and it never fails:  When something isn't working, the solution always involves simplifying the code, not adding to it.

Comment: BTW, I still wonder how I would finish off the original code.

Comment: Hmm, the SalesData example was just a small table for testing this. I tried to extend this to the actual production situation.  I used Top Priced Rank. = RANKX( ALL( 'Cases'[Broker] ), [Priced.] ) -- and every entry in the table is again 1. The definition for [Priced.] is in the original answer above.  I don't see anything that's different from the simpler example.  Any idea why I'm again getting all 1's again?

Comment: Just drop the column name i.e. [Broker] and remove filters from the entire table: RANKX( ALL( 'Cases' ), [Priced] )